# Create folder inside GKE nodes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I create some folder inside GKE node-pool like `/mnt/disks/abc` and `/mnt/disks/def` inside node-pool. When my node-pool get restarted, it will return to original state with no folder like `abc` and `def` inside `/mnt/disks`. Here some my configuration about deployment and storage.

###### pods configuration

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  serviceName: "test"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: test
        image: some.gcr.io/some-project/test:latest
        imagePullPolicy: "Always"
        volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /mnt/disks/
              name: test-vol
      volumes:
        - name: test-vol
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: some-pvc
      nodeSelector:
        node-pool: some-node
```

###### storage configuration

```yaml
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: some-storage
  namespace: default
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
reclaimPolicy: Retain
parameters:
  type: pd-ssd
allowVolumeExpansion: true
volumeBindingMode: Immediate

---

kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: some-pv
  namespace: default
spec:
  storageClassName: some-storage
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  local:
    path: "/mnt/disks"
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: node-pool
          operator: In
          values:
          - some-node
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: some-pvc
  namespace: default
spec:
  storageClassName: some-storage
  volumeName: some-pv
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
```

Is it possible to make folder `abc` and `def` to be persistent inside node-pool ? I just want to make these folder always existed when node-pool being restarted.

Thank you.

Comment: We need a few more details to understand exactly what you are trying to do here.  Can you sure your deployment spec (yaml)?

Comment: Sorry @GariSingh, i updated some information. Thanks.

Comment: One quick thing - GCE PD does not support `ReadWriteMany` ... are you sure your volume is being created in the first place?

Comment: Yes, it's already created. Some of my pod already using it. It's supported now for `RadWriteMany`. [Here for further information](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/persistent-volumes). Thanks @GariSingh.